# How can I make the trailing sell move up with price and not go down when price reverse without using the high of the current candle in PineScript

Tags: trailing

How can I make the trailing sell move up with price and not go down when price reverse without using the high of the current candle in PineScript

```
//@version=4
study("Trailing Sell ", overlay=true)

//--------------------------------------------TRAILING SELL-------------------------------------------

//TRAILING SELL LINE

show_drop_labels = input(true, title="Show Labels Trailing Below")
trailing_sell_offset = input(-0.2, title="Red Trailing Sell Line % Set Above Current Price", maxval=100, step=0.1)
    

src = close // should trail up behind current price and not the candle(high). should trail up and stop if price reverse. 
sumbars2 = 1
color_sell = color.red
per_calc = (sum(src,sumbars2)/sumbars2)*(1+(trailing_sell_offset/100))

trailing_sell_line = line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=per_calc,
     x2=bar_index[13], y2=per_calc, width=1, color=color_sell)

line.set_extend(trailing_sell_line, extend.none)
line.delete(trailing_sell_line[1])

//TRAILING SELL LABEL

var line l12 = na
if show_drop_labels 
   
    label trailing_sell_label = label.new(bar_index[12] , per_calc, "Trailing Sell Line", textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_right, color=color_sell, size=size.tiny )
    
    line.delete(l12[1])
    label.delete(trailing_sell_label[1])
```